# Android PowerManagerService code to handle Screen standby or Auto lock

Tags: android, android-source

In Android Source code Android\mydroid\frameworks\base\services\java\com\android\server\ **PowerManagerService.java which method I need to comment or change so that my Screen never goes in standby mode or gets Auto lock.**

I tried creating a service which captures boot complete intent. Tried capturing in broadcast receiver still the lock screen comes and goes.

Do let me know how I can disable screen auto lock and standby after system bootup.

I will make changes in the java file and again build the source code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method called doKeyguard which is called from systemReady in PhoneWindowManager. You can give that flow a try.